# How to get height of view of one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I have 3 tabs. 1 tab has a viewpager. I want to get the height of a view of a item in the viewpager so I can use it in my tab. If I try to access the fragment in onResume then the view is always null.

Layout for the Tab

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pager_indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/page_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/explore_indicator_outof"
        android:textColor="@color/metadata_main"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/out_of_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/explore_indicator_total"
        android:textColor="@color/metadata_grey"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for  a item inside a view pager. I want to get the value from top of screen to end of cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/page_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/bundle_item_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bundle_item_page_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bundle_header_height"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView.../>
    />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bundle_card_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/bundle_card_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bundle_card_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="@integer/bundle_item_orientation">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/bundle_text_layout_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <bunch of views/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what problem you are trying to solve, post some images and your layouts..

Comment: I'm trying to get the height of a view inside the viewpager so I can set a view pager indicator at the correct height.

Comment: please post your layouts